# Kotlin restricts certain annotations for some class

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, restriction

I have a class and it must not be `serializable`. If any developer accidentally annotates the class with Serializable, it should generate some kind of error/warning message during compilation or runtime.

```
class A() //Work OK

@Serializable
class A()    //Will have some kind of warning/error generated
```

Any way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible/acceptable to just write a unit test for this?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible before compile-time. Maybe some kind of special annotation processor or marker-annotation would be suitable for this

Comment: Is it only for one specific class? How about a comment on the class explaining why it shouldn't be made serializable? (otherwise a unit test ensuring the absence of the annotation as Slaw pointed out)

Comment: You will need to write a kotlin compiler plugin for this, is there some kind of pattern you can use to identify the classes that you don't want `@Serializable` to be attached to ?

Comment: I'll go for Unit Test, an easest and can work with project pipeline well. Thank All